# Specify then LOCK the line --LENGTH-- for a drawing

Tags: microsoft-visio, newlines

I am sketching out a section of my backyard with trees, a fences, and some big rocks to determine how large of a shed I can put "in the backyard." Measurements to all the trees have been made from a common centerpoint, and I measured the tree to tree distance. In essence, the area is broken into triangles of varying sizes WITH A COMMON FOCUS (the center spot).

To complete the Visio drawing, the common center point is a 12in x 12in circle and each "tree" is the same size circle (I don't need the drawing to the 1/8 of an inch, just a close whole measurement). Lines from the center to each tree are drawn, then from tree to tree are drawn AND..the specific lengths MUST be set at what I specify. Currently the drawing has a center, one tree, and one line which changes length if I move the tree.

How can I specify the lock / secure / prevent changes to the line length?

Comment: I can add a JPG of the hand sketch but don't see how to upload it.

Comment: Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Are you using a line or a connector? It might be best to upload your visio file (Dropbox, OneDrive etc.)

Comment: 1. Upload the image?....ok but wouldn't the VSD file be better?? I'll do the image

Comment: Just using a line, not a connector.

Comment: IMGUR: https://imgur.com/a/rrncgid